# ksh history not working on Linux

Tags: command-line, ksh

OK, I am a `vi` addict, and `ksh` user, and am addicted to command-line history editing using `vi` commands.  I am now on a Linux server and even though I have ksh as my login shell, and have set and exported the following environment variables, my command line editing is acting like the bash shell.

```
Unix> uname -s -r -v -m -p -i -o
Linux 3.8.13-98.4.1.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Wed Sep 23 18:34:15 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Select environment variables:

```
EDITOR=vi
ENV=/home/mark/.kshrc
FCEDIT=vi
HISTCMD=864
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HISTEDIT=vi
HISTFILE=/home/mark/.ksh_history
HISTFILESIZE=1000
HISTSIZE=1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm, when I saw `ENV=/home/mark/.kshrc` I don't remember creating that, so I looked in there and saw this:

```
# use emacs editing mode by default
set -o emacs
```

So I changed it to

```
set -o vi
```

and now I am happy!